# Three Images Aren't fully displayed on iPhone ( using meta viewport ) , not a custom version

Tags: html, css

Last final question about this thread, 
I have a table that contains 2 tr - table rows and 3 td for a row.

Code:

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;margin: 0 auto;max-width:100%;">
<table style='position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;'>
 <tr>
     <td><a href="/styles/Images/SLone.jpg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLone.jpg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
     <td>
     <a href="/styles/Images/SLtwo.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLtwo.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
    <td>
    <a href="/styles/Images/SLthree.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
    <img src='/styles/Images/SLthree.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
    </a>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
     <a href="/styles/Images/SLfour.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLfour.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
     <td>
     <a href="/styles/Images/SLfive.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLfive.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
    <td>
    <a href="/styles/Images/SLsix.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
    <img src='/styles/Images/SLsix.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
    </a>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

It is working great, except iPhone , You can only see 2 images and abit of the 3rd in a row, it's like the width is too much.

Hope there is a way to fix this , to make the table max-width:100% of screen , though it doesn't work .
Thanks alot,
 Elroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your body css:

```
min-width:1024px
```

and make sure your viewport is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```